# When defining S3 methods, should I explicitly import the generic method?

Tags: r

I've created a new class which has its own implementation of `simulate`, `anova` and `residuals`. When I create an R-package containing these methods I have to explicitly import the `simulate` function by including the following line in the `NAMESPACE` file:

```
importFrom(stats,simulate)
```

If I don't do this, then the package will fail `devtools::check()` and `R CMD check`. However, the package passes the checks even if I don't explicitly import `anova` or `residuals`.

Why is there a difference between `simulate` and the other methods and should I explicitly import all generic methods that I reimplement?

Comment: Is it because there is no simulate.default implementation defined in the stats package?

Comment: You could try `import("stats")` to import them all.

Comment: @andrew.punnett There's also no `anova.default`... Your question is actually two questions: (1) Why is there a difference between `simulate` and the others? and (2) Should I explicitly import all generics I provide methods for? I have an answer for (2), but not (1). Re: (2), see [Writing R Extensions, Section 1.5.2](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Registering-S3-methods): "To ensure that [S3] methods are available **the packages defining the methods should ensure that the generics are imported** and register the methods using S3method directives." (emphasis added)

Comment: Thanks. After reading your comment and re-reading the manual I think I understand what's going on. If you post your comment as an answer I'll assign you the bounty.